# C++ thread safe bound queue returning object for original thread to delete - 1 writer - 1 reader

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, data-structures

The goal is to have a writer thread and a reader thread but only the writer `new`s and `delete`s the action object.  There is only one reader and one writer.

something like:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t MAX>
class TSQ
{
public:
     // blocks if there are MAX items in queue
     // returns used Object to be deleted or 0 if none exist
     T * push(T * added); // added will be processed by reader

     // blocks if there are no objects in queue
     // returns item pushed from writer for deletion
     T * pop(T * used); // used will be freed by writer

private:
     // stuff here
};
```

-or better if the delete and return can be encapsulated:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t MAX>
class TSQ
{
public:
     // blocks if there are MAX items in queue
     push(T * added); // added will be processed by reader

     // blocks if there are no objects in queue
     // returns item pushed from writer for deletion
     T& pop();

private:
     // stuff here
};
```

where the writer thread has a loop like:

```
my_object *action;
while (1) {
    // create action
    delete my_queue.push(action);
}
```

and the reader has a loop like:

```
my_object * action=0;
while(1) {
     action=my_queue.pop(action);
     // do stuff with action
}
```

The reason to have the writer delete the action item is for performance

Is there an optimal way to do this?

Bonus points if MAX=0 is specialized to be unbounded (not required, just tidy)

*I'm not looking for the full code, just the data structure and general approach*

Comment: I've done something similar in an old project of mine: https://github.com/dutt/trassel. Basically condition variables are your friend but be careful how you use them. If I remember correctly they give false positives in some instances so you want a loop around them.

Comment: I've done this a few ways but have never been satisfied with it, the simplest way is two vectors (one inbound - one outbound) and using mutex, was thinking of a circular array and then the encapsulated delete is easier, but wanted ideas, and was hoping for maybe an atomic solution

Comment: How does signaling the object back to the queue writer, purely for deletion, improve performance?  The queue writer may well not be the originator of the object - it may have passed through several queues before it's purpose is over, though you could get round this by descending every inter-thread comms object from one that contains a reference to the queue upon which the originator will be waiting.  Returning an object to a general object pool, for re-use so avoiding continual new/delete, I can understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is an instance of the [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem). A popular way to solve this is to use a [lockfree queue](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2b%2b%20lockfree%20queue).

Also, the first practical change you might want to make is to add a sleep(0) into the production/consumption loops, so you will give up your time slice every iteration and won't end up using 100% of a CPU core.

Comment: how would this return the allocated object when the reader is done with it?  It also doesn't seem to be bounded.

Answer (score 0):

The most common solution to this problem is to pass values, not pointers. 
You can pass shared_ptr to this queue. Your queue doesn't need to know how to free memory after you.

If you use something like Lamport's ring buffer for single producer - single consumer blocking queue, it's a natural solution to use std::vector under the hood that will call destructors for every element automatically.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t MAX>
class TSQ
{
public:
     // blocks if there are MAX items in queue
     void push(T added); // added will be processed by reader

     // blocks if there are no objects in queue
     T pop();

private:
     std::vector<T> _content;
     size_t _push_index;
     size_t _pop_index;
     ...
};
```